# Join the elements of generators lists

Tags: python, join, generator

I have two generators lists:

- `letters= ('AA', 'AB',...,'AZ)`
  `digits= (0,1,2,3,...,9)`

From letters and digits, I would like to obtain a third generator `list (names)`, so that:

- `names= ('AA0', 'AA1'.., 'AA9', 'AB0',..'AB9',...'AZ0',...,'AZ9')`.

I've tried  for a couple of days to achieve 'names' with `itertools` functions but I cannot achieve the desired result.

The last thing I tried was:

```
'''
names= dict((key, digits) for key in letters)

def naming():
    for key in names.keys():
        for dig in names.values():
            yield(''.join('{}{}'.format(key, dig)))

names= ('{}{}'.format(key, value) for key, value in names.items())
'''
```

But it doesn't work, and I definitely want a generator list.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

letters = ("AA", "AB")
digits = (0,9)

["".join(p) for p in product(letters, map(str, digits))]
```

Output:

```
['AA0', 'AA9', 'AB0', 'AB9']
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong in this snippet is iterating over `names.values()` in inner loop.

```
>>> let=['a','b','c']
>>> dig=[1,2,3]
>>> nms=dict((key, dig) for key in let)
>>> nms
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> nms.values()
dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
```

You should rewrite it as

```py
def fn():
 for k in nms.keys():
  for d in nms[k]:
   yield(''.join('{}{}'.format(k,d)))
list(fn())
# ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```